# Adobe Reader - How to print by specifying physical page numbers

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader

I am using Adobe Reader 10.0.1. I have a pdf file which has overlapping logical page numbers. For example Chapter 1 has a page 9 but Chapter 2, 3, etc. do also have a page number 9. So, I would like to set physical page numbers in the print dialog but I can't find any such option. Here is a screenshot of the dialog:

[image]

**How can I print by specifying physical page numbers?**

**Update**

To clarify where I input the page numbers, I upload two pictures (I input the number into the red rectangle and see the physical page number but cannot modify it in the yellow one in the second image):
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hopefully somebody with more patience, then I, will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Edit menu go into Preferences, then select Page Display, and check the box `Use Logical Page Numbers`. See if your page numbers are updated. That should work with this version.

[More Information Here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/797699)